# using hashset values as keys in a hashmap

Tags: java, initialization, hashmap, declaration, hashset

My problem is that I have 2 classes one called Set this contains a hashset of values, now these values in the hashset have the used as keys in a hashmap that is in a seperate class called Map and I dont have a clue where to start but it has to be something small

Comment: Your question is far too vague to answer at the moment. You haven't said anything about what's actually wrong. Please produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Re: "these values in the hashset have the used as keys in a hashmap": Implementation experience suggests that it's actually simpler to create a set using a map, rather than the other way round. For example, in the JDK, `HashSet<E>` and `TreeSet<E>` are backed by `HashMap<E,Object>` and `TreeMap<E,Object>` (respectively), with static dummy objects as the sole values.

Answer (score 0):

Well in general, if you want to seed your HashMap with the keys from the HashSet, you could do something like:

```
HashSet<KeyClass> set;
HashMap<KeyClass,ValueClass> map = new HashMap<KeyClass,ValueClass>();

for (KeyClass key : set) {
   map.put( key, new ValueClass() );
}
```